# TypeError from Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, typescript

I made an express app, and it has an app inside of that called users. I am using Typescript. This is what my app.js file looks like:

```
///<reference path='d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts' />
///<reference path='d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/express/express.d.ts' />
///<reference path='routes/Users.ts' />

import express = require("express");
import http = require("http");
import path = require("path");
import us = require("./routes/Users");

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('env', 'development');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("index", {
        title: "Express Main Page"
    });
});


// Users app
app.use(us.Users.users);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Right now, the problem is this, I am using mongoose to store some data, and I have mongodb started. Here is what the Users.ts file looks like:

```
/// <reference path='../d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='../d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/express/express.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='../d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts' />

import express = require("express");
import mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/SimpleBlog");

export module Users {

    // Exporting information about the user class
    export var users: Express = express();
    export var base_URL: string = "/users";

    // Making Schemas
    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        email: String,
        name: String,
        age: Number
    });

    // Attaining users
    var db_Users = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);

    var list;
    db_Users.find({}, (err, docs) => {
        list = docs;
        console.log(docs);
    });

    // Route for base url
    users.get(base_URL, (req, res) => {
        res.render("Users/index", {
            title: "User List",
            user_list: list
        });
    });


    // Route for POST request
    users.post(base_URL + "/add", (req, res) => {

        try {
            console.log(req.body['name']);

            new UserSchema({
                name: req.body['name'],
                email: req.body['email'],
                age: req.body['age']
            }).save(function (err, docs) {
                    if (err) { console.log(err); }
                });
        } catch (Exception) {
            console.log(Exception);
        }
        res.redirect(base_URL);
    });

    users.get(base_URL + "/add", (req, res) => {
        res.render("Users/add", {});
    });

}
```

I get `[TypeError: object is not a function]` as the error, when I try to save.

The `users/add` simple gives the user a registration form, and this is done in a jade file. I can also attest that it is not a problem with `express.bodyParser()` since `console.log(req.body['name']);` prints out the name of the post request correctly.

Any help regarding this would be helpful.

Comment: You might want to go more low level : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mongodb/mongodb-tests.ts 

After all its just json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax isn't correct for Mongoose.

Regarding this line:

```
// Attaining users
var db_Users = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

That line returns a `Model` function/[constructor](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html). You'll use that result to create instances of a `User`. Given all of the Users/UserSchema/User namespace you've got right now, it's a little confusing, so I'll switch it:

```
// Attaining users
var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

It looks like the class represents a User, not Users.

When you want to create an instance of a User, you'd create an instance of the `UserModel` class rather than the schema:

```
new UserModel({
    name: req.body['name'],
    email: req.body['email'],
    age: req.body['age']
}).save(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been at it for some time. I can't believe the mistake was that stupid.